# Convert all occurrences of px to rem for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I am a noob web developer and made a big mistake.
I am creating a website for a college project, it needs to be responsive. I have tons of CSS written all in px units. But now for responsiveness, I want to convert all the px to rem. It would be a tiring task to do it one by one. Is there any tool that can help me?

Comment: Do you have a font-size set on root? If not then default per rem is 16px

Comment: @zer00ne No, I dont have it set, my root sets only margin and padding to 0px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that would automatically change all px to rems but you can make the changes quickly if you do something like this:

```
body {
   font-size: 0.625rem; 
{
```

Now 1 rem will be equal to 10 px, if you use Vscode you can enter a shortcut `Ctrl + F` and choose a *Use Regular Expression* option in Find input.
Then you can type `(\d*)?(\d).?(\d*)?px` in Find field, and `$1.$2$3rem` in Replace field.
But be alert, this regex doesn't work for sizes beginning with dot like `.5px`.

The search bar should look like this:
[image]

If you want to learn how this regular expression works click [here](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### Regex shouldn't be used this way, but...

This function should work but the predicament you are in is usually a one time thing and I normally advise against using Regex in this manner. The function `pxToRem()`:

- Finds all occurrences of a number (even with a decimal) adjacent to the letters 'px'.
- Then a replacer function takes the number part and divides it by 16
- Next it suffixes the new number with 'rem' and replaces the old number and 'px'.

### Usage

- Open your stylesheet, select as much of the text you need to change and copy it.
- Next, paste it on a blank .html or .js file.
- Wrap the text in grave marks ```` ``` ```` on a QWERTY keyboard it's the key located upper left hand corner <kbd>`~</kbd>
- Assign the string to a variable.
- Copy and paste `pxToRem()` code to the same page.

```js
let css = `.box {width: 32px; height: 16px; border: 6px; padding 2.5px;}`;

function pxToRem(CSSString) {
  const rgx = new RegExp(/(\d+\.?\d*)px/, 'g');
  return CSSString.replace(rgx, (match, n) => (n / 16) + 'rem');
}

console.log(pxToRem(css));
```

Keep in mind that `rem` are relative to the `font-size` set on `:root/html` and if that `font-size` happens to be absolute (like the default of 16px) then the styles with `rem` aren't responsive, but they have the potential to be responsive. If you use a `vmin` units all `rem` will react immediately to any changes to the viewport. This not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Its a bit lenghty bu its much accurate results.

Comment: lol lengthy? It's 2 lines and dealing with regex can get really ugly . Anyways glad it helped.

Comment: I am sorry if the word lengthy hurt you. By lengthy, I meant that process is lengthy,means we have to copy paste creat a file and all that work. I am really sorry if it hurt you.

Comment: No, I wasn't hurt just amused, but yes the process is just a one time thing, if there was  a reoccuring need to do this, then more functions would definitely be needed. But the nature of how CSS is implemented on stylesheets has very little in the way of access and manipulation. CSSOM has been around but it's sketchy and not that useful yet.